# Comparing two data frames using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, df1 and df2. I want to create a for loop that "runs" over the first columns of both df1 and df2 (column 1) and return me the element found on column 0 of df2. My code so far is the following, but something goes wrong.

```
import pandas as pd

def user_return(df1,df2,list):
    for i in df1.iteritems():
        for j in df2.iteritems():
            if df1[i:1] == df2[j:1]:
                list.append(df2[j:0])

    return list
```

Could you please give me a hand? Thanx.

Comment: Why don't you inner join and then return the column from the join i.e. the values which are found in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're wondering how to implement my suggestion from the comments:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"], data=[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"], data=[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]])

merged = df1.merge(df2, on="Col1")
both_col_vals = list(merged["Col1"])
print both_col_vals
```

Output >> [1,2,3]